# Need assistance with configuring a progressbar that works on multiple threads in Powershell

Tags: multithreading, powershell, progress-bar, exchangewebservices

I'm finishing up a script that I have been working on for a while now, and the last few pieces of the script I'd like to include a progressbar so that whoever runs it, has a general idea of how far it is to being completed.

The script imports contacts into Exchange. Everything works great. The way that it works, I have several hundred mailboxes that I need to import several hundred contacts to.

When the script runs; let's say I have my threads configured to run 10 threads at a time. So each thread that is running represents a mailbox that it is binded to and is importing contacts into.

So basically I would like 10 progressbars (or however many threads I have running simultaneously). And once 1 thread is completed, a new one starts up with the next mailbox in queue and continues until all mailboxes have imported all the contacts.

I hope this makes sense. Here is the code I am working with. It's part of a scriptblock that is executed by start-threadjob.

```
$global:progressParams = @{}
# initiate counter for progress
[System.Int32]$j = '1'

$emailaddresses | ForEach-Object{
    $UPN = $_

    $scriptBlock = {
        ########### Pass our Variables we wll need to this scope ###########

        $UPN = $using:UPN
        $headers = $using:headers
        $FolderName = $using:FolderName
        $Users = $using:Users
        $rootPath = $using:rootPath
        $AccessToken = $using:AccessToken
        $NewContactFolder = $using:NewContactFolder

        ##################### Grab Contact Folder Info #####################
        
        $Timer = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()

        $global:folderId = & "$rootPath\ConfigureContactsFolder\ConfigureContactsFolder.ps1"

        Add-Content "$rootPath\progress.txt" "`tFinished Setting up Contact Folder for $UPN in:$($Timer.Elapsed.ToString()) seconds"
        Add-Content "$rootPath\progress.txt" ""
        
        ##################### Getting Contact Info #####################
        
        if(($NULL -ne $folderId) -and ($NULL -eq $NewContactFolder))
        {
            $Timer = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()

            $global:Contacts = & "$rootPath\GetContactInfo\GetContactInfo.ps1"

            Add-Content "$rootPath\progress.txt" "`tFinished Getting all Contact Info for $UPN in:$($Timer.Elapsed.ToString()) seconds"
            Add-Content "$rootPath\progress.txt" ""
        }

        ##################### Import Contacts #####################
        
        if($NULL -eq $Contacts)
        {
            $Timer = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew() 

            & "$rootPath\ContactImport\ContactImport.ps1"

            Add-Content "$rootPath\progress.txt" "`tFinished Importing Contacts for $UPN in:$($Timer.Elapsed.ToString()) seconds"
            Add-Content "$rootPath\progress.txt" ""           
        }        
    }
    Start-ThreadJob -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock

    while(((get-job).State) -contains "Running")
    {
        $progressParams = @{
            Activity = "Processing user - $($UPN)"
            PercentComplete = $j / $Users.count * 100
            Status = "Remaining: $($Users.count - $j) out of $($Users.count)"
        }

        Write-Progress @progressParams

        $j++
    }
}

CLS
Write-Host "Importing Contacts..."

while(((get-job).State) -contains "Running")
{
    <#
    $progressParams = @{
            Activity = "Processing user - $($UPN)"
            PercentComplete = $j / $Users.count * 100
            Status = "Remaining: $($Users.count - $j) out of $($Users.count)"
        }

    Write-Progress @progressParams

        $j++
        #>
}

$result = Get-Job | Receive-Job -Wait

# Free up memory:
Get-Job | Remove-Job

Add-Content "$rootPath\progress.txt" "`t`tFinished Full script in:$($FinalTimer.Elapsed.ToString()) seconds"
Add-Content "$rootPath\progress.txt" ""
Add-Content "$rootPath\progress.txt" "------------------------------------------------------------------------"
```

Comment: Using Jobs, there's been a few attempts to do this. I wanted to add this to many of my scripts over the years but was never able to find the time, since it's mostly just a nice-to-have. This Microsoft MVP seems to have come up with something for jobs:

https://dille.name/blog/2015/09/11/displaying-progress-from-powershell-jobs/

If I had to do anything like this now, I would try using Foreach -Parallel:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/write-progress-across-multiple-threads?view=powershell-7.1

Comment: Thanks I'll give that a look when I'm back at work. The first links looks promising. The 2nd link might not be the best because I'm not using Powershell 7.

Comment: The first link was a bit helpful, but for some reason I'm still running into issues. For example $job.childjobs returns NULL also $job.Progress. when I print out $job | fl, I see a bunch of stuff but most of the values are empty {}.